# My PHP file doesn't run the JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php

I've posted the full code, but the problem lies in the button within the foreach loop. I've made an onclick JavaScript function, but when I click the button, nothing happens. Would someone give me a hint?

I'm sure the rest works fine.

Here's the code:

```
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<script "text/javascript">

function show_your_message(subject,message){
<?php echo "1" ?>
$_SESSION['subject'] = subject;
$_SESSION['message'] = message;
location.href = 'show_messgae.php';
}
</script>
<?php    

require 'db.php';

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['email'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM account_inbox WHERE inbox_user = '$id'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

$type_array = array();
$from_user_array = array();
$page_link_array = array();
$message_array = array();
$subject_array = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($type_array,$row['type']);
array_push($from_user_array,$row['from_user']);
array_push($page_link_array,$row['page_link']);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user = '$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($message_array,$row['message']);
array_push($subject_array,$row['subject']);
}

include 'header.php';
if (isset($_SESSION["email"]) && !empty($_SESSION["email"])) { 
?>


<section id="middle_table">
<div class='post feed'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <table>

<tr>
<th>from</th>
<th>message type</th>
<th>Go to message</th>
</tr>



                    <?php foreach (range(0, $rowcount - 1) as $i): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $from_user_array[$i]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $type_array[$i]; ?></td>
                            <td><button onclick="show_your_message('<?php 
                            echo $subject_array[$i]; ?>','<?php echo $message_array[$i]; ?>') "> Click to open</button></td>
                        </tr>


                    <?php endforeach; ?>
             </table>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Next" style="float: right; cursor: pointer;">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Previous" style="float: right; cursor: pointer;">
</div>
    </div>
</div>
 </section>


  </body>
   </html>

<?php } 
else {
    echo "<h1> You are not logged in </h1>";
} ?>
```

Comment: `show_messgae` misspelling

Comment: It looks like you have php in your javascript function. the php is ran before the javascript would be ran. So your handler might be empty.  and location.href is inside of php, but that looks like javascript code.

Comment: You are using php variables outside php tags

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a bit on what [Jay said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571244/1447862), and taking into account what I think you're trying to accomplish, you could replace your javascript function with this:

```js
function show_your_message(subject,message){
    location.href = "show_message.php?subject=" + subject + '&message=' + message;
}
```

In `show_message.php` you get the values from the query string and set them in your PHP file.

Depending on the size of subject and message, query string may not be a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set PHP variables with JavaScript as you try to do here:

```
function show_your_message(subject,message){
    <?php echo "1" ?>
    $_SESSION['subject'] = subject;
    $_SESSION['message'] = message;
    location.href = 'show_messgae.php';
}
```

This should've thrown error messages (check your browser's console) as you are not even putting the SESSION values in PHP tags.

In order to set SESSION variables from JavaScript you'll have to use AJAX to send the values to a PHP script for processing. Keep in mind that remotely setting SESSION variables can be problematic as those are not reflected in the current page as you would expect, unless you reload the current page after setting them.

The other alternative is doing a page reload (no JavaScript necessary) in which you set the SESSION values.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to anwser my question!!! you really helped me!!!